# MySQL Remove word group distinguish by , from the field string

Tags: mysql, database

In mysql database i would like to remove a string/portion from a field/column

My fields "data" contain as follows -

```
1-----------,IDEA;T;P;N,VODAFONE;R;T;P;N,AIRCEL;R;T;N,---------------
2-----------,IDEA;T;P;N,VODAFONE;R;T;N,AIRCEL;R;T;N,---------------
3-----------,IDEA;T;P;N,VODAFONE;R;N,AIRCEL;R;T;N,---------------
4-----------,IDEA;T;P;N,VODAFONE;R;T;P,AIRCEL;R;T;N,---------------
```

here in this data a portion is distingquish by , that means the "VODAFONE;R;T;P;N" will be denote as one word or group.

Now how can I remove the IDEA Group or VODAFONE Group or AIRCEL group from the field.

```
e.g. UPDATE mytable SET data="-----------,IDEA;T;P;N,AIRCEL;R;T;N,---------------"(olddata removing VODAFONE Group)
```

Comment: It surely looks like a very strange database design. Have you read something about [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and [Atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Atomicity) in particular?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Right Now I am working on some other database and I can not do anything on it. So I am helpless now. I have to delete a portion from the field. Can u help me out.

Answer (score 1):

```
 UPDATE mytable SET data=
 CASE
 WHEN data LIKE '%VODAFONE;R;T;P;N,%' THEN REPLACE(data,'VODAFONE;R;T;P;N,','')
 WHEN data LIKE '%VODAFONE;R;N,%' THEN REPLACE(data,'VODAFONE;R;N,','')
 WHEN data LIKE '%VODAFONE;T;P;N,%' THEN REPLACE(data,'VODAFONE;T;P;N,','')
 WHEN data LIKE '%VODAFONE;R;T,%' THEN REPLACE(data,'VODAFONE;R;T,','')
 END
 WHERE data LIKE '%VODAFONE%'
```

Replace 'VODAFONE blah' with the string you want removed.This will remove it in all fields.
EDIT.Just put in all your cases,if you need more.

Comment: Thanks it works for the exact value 'VODAFONE;R;T;P;N,' but in some field it contain as 'VODAFONE;R;N,' or 'VODAFONE;T;P;N,' or 'VODAFONE;R;T;' how can we handled this kind of situation

Comment: awsome, suppose if we don't know what r after the Vodafone. As I have already mention the word or Group is distinguish by , and I want to remove a particular group containing vodafone.